# Objective C String Containing Quotes

Tags: objective-c

Okay I am fairly new to objective C I fallowed the full tutorial set on lynda.com and it got me quite a long ways but there is something I just came across that has confused me.

Here is my code. Just building for fun

```
    NSString * sFeedURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bing.com/search?q=google+stock&go=&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=google+stock&sc=8-9&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=b4b9ac10d0344ddb9c5c6eab5dfc28fb"];

    NSString * sActualFeed = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:sFeedURL] encoding:1 error:nil];

    NSArray *sPageRanks = [sActualFeed componentsSeparatedByString:@"<h2><a href=""];
```

So all it dose is pull the html from Bing for the search Google stock. But I want it to then start striping the information it gets back doing this as a test for string functions / methods

In most other language I have learned we would then put a slash in front of my " or just wrap the string in single quotes but that dose not work in objective c.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\" there\'s a quotation mark to my left."];`

Comment: This is no different from C or Java, at least one of which you should have learned before starting into Objective-C.

Comment: *"In most other language I have learned we would then put a **slash** in front of my " "* - I would be interested in an example, because in most languages that *I* know it is a backslash.

Comment: Sorry Martin I meant to say backslash And thank you Carpetfizz.

Also hot licks I learned C++ I must have miss typed the statement I used with the backslash before cause I got a error. None the less thank you for the help tremendously